# Optimizing C code, Horner's polynomial evaluation

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, polynomials

I'm trying to learn how to optimize code (I'm also learning C), and in one of my books there's a problem for optimizing Horner's method for evaluation polynomials. I'm a little lost on how to approach the problem. I'm not great at recognizing what needs optimizing.

Any advice on how to make this function run faster would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
 double polyh(double a[], double x, int degree) {
        long int i;
        double result = a[degree];
        for (i = degree-1; i >= 0; i--) 
            result = a[i] + x*result;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: It's the `for` loop that could be optimized.  When `degree` is large the `for` loop will take a long time.

Comment: If you need to evaluate the polynomial at a set of points with size k = `degree`, then you can do the job in O(k log^3 k) vs O(k^2) for naive Horners' using Discrete Fourier Transforms. This is a nice savings. Check any good resource on DFT's for the method.

Comment: Obligatory Use a profiler to see what your costs are.

Answer (score 3):

You really need to profile your code to test whether proposed optimizations really help. For example, it may be the case that declaring `i` as `long int` rather than `int` slows the function on your machine, but on the other hand it may make no difference on your machine but might make a difference on others, etc. Anyway, there's no reason to declare `i` a `long int` when `degree` is an `int`, so changing it probably won't hurt. (But still profile!)

Horner's rule is supposedly optimal in terms of the number of multiplies and adds required to evaluate a polynomial, so I don't see much you can do with it. One thing that *might* help (profile!) is changing the test `i>=0` to `i!=0`. Of course, then the loop doesn't run enough times, so you'll have to add a line below the loop to take care of the final case.

Alternatively you could use a `do { ... } while (--i)` construct. (Or is it `do { ... } while (i--)`? You figure it out.)

You might not even need `i`, but using `degree` instead will likely not save an observable amount of time and will make the code harder to debug, so it's not worth it.

Another thing that *might* help (I doubt it, but profile!) is breaking up the arithmetic expression inside the loop and playing around with order, like

```
for (...) {
  result *= x;
  result += a[i];
}
```

which may reduce the need for temporary variables/registers. Try it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Some suggestion:**

1. You may use `int` instead of `long int` for looping index.

Comment: Can you make this suggestion without knowing the processor's word width?

Comment: @FiddlingBits `int degree` does not need `long int i` to iterate, or indeed index an array.

Comment: If the word width is `sizeof(long int)`, then it wouldn't help, right?

Comment: @Fiddling Bits If a wider integer type is faster than `int`, a good compiler, optimized for speed, will use it.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly the problem is inviting you to conjecture on the values of `a`.  If that vector is mostly zeros, then you'll go faster (by doing fewer `double` multiplications, which will be the clear bottleneck on most machines) by computing only the values of `a[i] * x^i` for `a[i] != 0`.  In turn the `x^i` values can be computed by careful repeated squaring, preserving intermediate terms so that you never compute the same partial power more than once. [See the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) if you've never implemented repeated squaring.